# Keep getting runtime error 429 "ActiveX component can't create object"

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to build a vba to get data from another sheet on a network drive location. Created a .xlsm file and got the 429 error so closed file, and reopening it gives an error that says there was a problem and says it can recover what it needs. Recreated a whole new file eventually after trying to fix it and stopped the error until the file was closed and same thing. Any ideas what is causing the issues?

Tried a cmd prompt

```
sfc /scannow
```

this is my vba, it gives an error on each marco

```
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
```

```
Sub DataPull()
    Dim folder As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim workbook2path As String
    Dim workbook2 As Workbook
    
    
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

folder = ws1.Range("B1").Value
file = ws1.Range("B2").Value
workbook2path = folder & "\" & file

If Dir(workbook2path) = "" Then
    MsgBox "DRG calc file does not exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

If workbook2path = "" Then
    MsgBox "File Path is missing from cell b2"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set workbook2 = Workbooks.Open(workbook2path)
workbook2.Windows(1).Visible = False
Set ws2 = workbook2.Sheets("Interactive DRG Calculator")

lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To lastrow
    ws2.Range("E9").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "F").Value
    ws2.Range("E10").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "G").Value
    ws2.Range("E11").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "G").Value
    ws2.Range("E12").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value
    ws2.Range("E13").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "J").Value
    ws2.Range("E16").Value = "'" & ws1.Cells(i, "K").Value
    ws2.Range("E17").Value = "'" & ws1.Cells(i, "L").Value
    
    workbook2.Save
    
    ws1.Cells(i, "N").Value = ws2.Range("E72").Value
Next i

workbook2.Close savechanges:=False



End Sub
```

```
Sub FileViewer()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim DropdownCell As Range
    Dim FileList As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FileExtension As String

    ' Set the folder path from cell B2
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the folder path in B2 is valid
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid folder path in cell B2."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set the worksheet and cell where you want the dropdown list
    Set DropdownCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ' Change "Sheet1" and "A1" to your actual sheet and cell reference

    ' Initialize the list of files
    FileList = ""

    ' Get a list of files in the folder
    FileExtension = Dir(FolderPath & "*.*")

    ' Check if any files were found
    If FileExtension <> "" Then
        Do While FileExtension <> ""
            FileList = FileList & FileExtension & ","
            FileExtension = Dir
        Loop

        ' Split the list into an array
        Dim FilesArray() As String
        FilesArray = Split(Left(FileList, Len(FileList) - 1), ",")

        ' Create the data validation list
        With DropdownCell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(FilesArray, ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No files found in the folder."
    End If
End Sub
```

Tried changing script variables, sheet names
scanned system found no corrupt files on scan
Only fix is to make new file and leave open

Comment: Have you tried using `WorkSheets` instead of `Sheets`? or is there a reason you need `Sheets`? (note: they are not the same thing)

Comment: Why `workbook2.Save` on every iteration ? Also because `workbook2path = folder & "\" & file` then `If workbook2path = ""` can never be true.

Comment: @braX Changing to `Worksheets` still has the activeX error, i'm starting to think some security issue on our network even though it shouldn't be.
@CDP1802 The path is supposed to trigger the error if the users run the DataPull macro before the other macro to get the files from the folder location. The workbook2.save is so it plugs the data into the other workbook that has formulas as for some reason it does not auto update the fields when the data is added until save, lots of parts are protected so they dont get messed up

Comment: Have you included any Active-X control references in the VBA Project? The code you posted does not reference any.

Comment: i added my other macro that gets the files in a dropdown list from whatever location is added to B1. From my knowledge, i don't think it includes ActiveX references. It can run perfectly fine when i make them, its just when the file is closed out it will reopen saying it found errors and needs to be recovered

Comment: `Join(FilesArray, ",")` - what is the typical total length of this string?  There's a limit of 256 characters, and you may be exceeding it.  If necessary, you can instead add the file names to a worksheet and point the DV list to that range.  Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022702/excel-found-unreadable-content-data-validation

Comment: @TimWilliams ah i didn't even thing about character limit being an option for the error. That could be why. I may just need to do that instead! ill have to try that one